# Alternative CDI implementation - WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Repository with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian, weld

I have an interface `Repository` with two implementations, `DBRepository` and `UTRepository`. `UTRepository` is annotated with `@Alternative` and I'm trying to use it in a JUnit test.

The test class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Inject
    private UserService service;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addClasses(Repository.class, UserService.class, UTRepository.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void addCharacterTest() {
        service.addCharacter(1L, Mockito.mock(GameCharacter.class));
    }
}
```

The class under test:

```
public class UserService {
    @Inject
    Repository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void addCharacter(Long userId, GameCharacter character) {
        User user = repository.readById(userId, User.class);
        user.addCharacter(character);
        repository.update(user);
    }
}
```

My `beans.xml` file (placed in src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_2.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <alternatives>
        <class>org.package.name.UTRepository</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

When I try to run the test, I get the exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Repository with qualifiers @Default
    at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.package.name.services.UserService.repository
    at org.package.name.services.UserService.repository(UserService.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found works well, so just for completness.

Basically you need to add `beans.xml` which will enable your alternative. `EmptyAsset.INSTANCE` will result in empty beans.xml which won't cut it in this case.

However, in your solution, the `beans.xml` you placed under `src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml` does nothing. *If you want to leverage an existing `beans.xml` file*, you can use:

- `addAsManifestResource(File resource, String target)` which adds given `File` as with name of `target`
- `addAsManifestResource(Package resourcePackage, String resourceName, String target)` which allows you to specify just the package where the file is, then its name and file the name under which you want it in your deployment

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `.addAsManifestResource` arguments. I have to use a `StringAsset` with the alternatives that Arquillian will add to beans.xml, not an empty instance.

This is the `createDeployment()` method now:

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
        .addClasses(Repository.class, UserService.class, UTRepository.class)
        .addAsManifestResource(new StringAsset("<alternatives><class>org.package.name.repositories.UTRepository</class></alternatives>"), "beans.xml");
}
```